# deploy with glassfish an updated .ear project

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

i'm working with a netbeans EE project, that creates a .ear file that has to be deployed with glassfish, and it contains an ejb and a war module.

but when i edit any of the .java files in war or in ejb, then i click on build, it won't change my .ear file (i can notice because it will still have the old save date).

what should be done to make the changes to take effect on the .ear file that is being deployed?

Comment: Have you verified that you are building the EAR project, not the web application or EJB jar project?

Comment: how can i find out the difference? because i open the folder project, and i know that inside it has the ejb and war project, but i don't understand which could be the way to build the .EAR project instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if you build a project while still within the WAR or EJB folder (that opens in netbeans if, when you open the project, you click on "open related project"), it will build only that folder.

So what should be done is really easy:

- click on the main EE folder on the sidebar of netbeans - the one called "projects"
- build (or clean and build)

you will notice that the compiler will create the .EAR file to deploy in glassfish, AKA the correct one if you want to create an enterprise application.